# facebook - how to get user id with phpsdk and js sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm implenting my fb app and it's connected to its own fb fanpage. I need to get a users info like username, id etc but when I click on my "Facebook authenticate" link, I end up going to a blank white page?
 You can view my code in here: http://codepad.org/f0Tuh63v

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', true);

 require 'facebook/facebook.php';

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => '1',
 'secret' => '2',
));


// See if there is a user from a cookie
 $user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
   // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
   print_r($user_profile);
   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
   $user = null;
 }
}
else{
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array('scope' => 'user_about_me,user_birthday,email,publish_actions,offline_access,user_hometown,user_location',
              'redirect_uri' => "https://domain.net/intro.php"
        )
); // end of array

}
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
      Your user profile is
     <pre>
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
     </pre>
   <?php } else { ?>

  <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Facebook authenticate</a>
    <?php } ?>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init({
        appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true,
      status: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      //window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      //window.location.reload();
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

It's also here http://codepad.org/f0Tuh63v
What am I doing wrong?

Also is there a way to get the FB user id without using phpsdk or the js sdk? Or do I have to use these plugins?

Comment: Ok.. So please mention that in the question itself that you have put the values of appid and secret correctly. Or use something like **** so that everyone understands that just by seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see what's wrong with your code. But, If you are using Javascript, I can tell you an alternative for getting authenticated and then getting the info you require.

I used the following code behind my button, which authenticated my Facebook app and then redirected the user to my website. It worked for me.

```
<a class="fb-login-button" align="center" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=token&scope=PERMISSION_1,PERMISSION_2&redirect_uri=YOUR_WEBSITE"> TEXT </a>
```

Then I extracted the token which was returned in the redirected URL.

```
var url_t; // Get the redirected URL.
access_token = url_t.split('=')[1].split('&')[0];
```

Then using the access token I sent the HTTP request for getting the required data. I used GRAPH API provided by facebook. For eg: For getting the first name of the user:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
var f_url_new = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20=%20me()&access_token=" + access_token;
xhr.open("GET", f_url_new , true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        obj1 = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var str = obj1.data[0].name.toString();
        var n=str.split(" ");
        document.getElementById("name").innerText = n[0];
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

Hope it gives you some idea with regards to the alternatives. This is not the correct answer to your question, but can help in the thought process.